# Parallel, Traveling Salesman algorithm Branch & Bound - via C and MPI

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a problem with this code, not written by me. This is the **traveling salesman algorithm with branch and bound**. The problem is that when I insert a 20x20 Matrix (so 20 knots), the program takes a long time. What could I change? I would like a result in less than 5 seconds… this takes about 2 minutes.

From the web(http://wyattgorman.com/?p=25), it is explained what this program must do:

“Node 0 is the master and doesn’t do any work, node 1 is the first worker, so it gets the branch that starts at city 0 and goes to city 1. Node 2 takes city 0 to city 2 and so on. If you have 20 nodes and the adjacency matrix is greater than 20 × 20, say 30 × 30, node 20 will get city 0 to city 20. Then city 0 to city 21 is again assigned to node 1 and city 0 to city 22 is assigned to node 2. The reporting of the low cost routes found is carried out by each node maintaining its best cost for the branch it is working on (ie from city 0 to city X). Once it has gone through the entire branch, it reports the best cost to the master. The master then compares the best cost with his own best operating cost and keeps track of the best winning cost, the winning path and the winning node. Then send the best cost of the master to the node to improve the future boundary.”

*This is The code:*

```
// Soluzione TSP con Branch and Bound

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define NODES 20
int m_row=NODES, m_column=NODES, zed=30, matrix[NODES][NODES], visited[NODES], best_path[NODES];
int best_cost=9999999, size=NODES;

void dfs(int city, int visited_in[], int path_in[], int path_i_in, int cost_in) {
  if (cost_in < best_cost) {
      int *visited=calloc(sizeof(int),size+1);
      int *path=calloc(sizeof(int),size+1);
      int path_i=path_i_in, cost=cost_in, i;

      for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        visited[i]=visited_in[i];
        path[i]=path_in[i];
      }

      visited[city]=1;
      path[path_i]=city;
      path_i++;

      int leaf=0;
      for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if(visited[i]==0) {
          leaf++;
          dfs(i, visited, path, path_i, cost+matrix[city][i]);
        }
      }
      if (leaf == 0) {
        cost+=matrix[city][0];
        path[path_i]=0;
        path_i++;

        if(cost < best_cost) {
          //printf(“Found new best cost: %i\n”, cost);
          best_cost=cost;
          for(i=0; i<size; i++)
            best_path[i]=path[i];
        }
      }

      free(visited);
      free(path);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

      int rank, p, source, dest;
      int tag=0;
      MPI_Status status;

      MPI_Init(0, NULL);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

      srand( time(NULL) );

      if (rank == 0) {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<m_row; i++) // i < 20
          for(j=0; j<m_column; j++) //j < 20
            matrix[i][j]=0;
        for ( i=0; i<m_row; i++ ) {
          for( j=0; j<i; j++ ) {
              if (i != j) {
                int temp=(rand()%zed)+1;
                matrix[i][j]=temp;
                matrix[j][i]=temp;
              }
          }
        }

        // Manda la matrice generata a tutti i processi
        for(i=1; i<p; i++) // p è il numero dei processi
          MPI_Send(&matrix[0][0], size*size, MPI_LONG, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        printf("Matrix, %lix%li, Max Int: %li\n", m_row, m_column, zed);
        for(i=0; i<m_row; i++) {
          for(j=0; j<m_column; j++)
            printf("%li\t", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
            fflush(NULL);
        }
        printf("\n");

        int winner;
        int node_array[p-1];
        int node_array_i=0;
        for(i=0; i<p-1; i++)
          node_array[i]=i+1;
        for(i=1; i<size; i++) { // size = 20
            int temp_best_cost, node;
            node=node_array[node_array_i]; // va a prendere node_array[0] perchè node_array_i = 0;
            if (node_array_i < p-2)
              node_array_i++;
            else
              node_array_i=0;

        int *temp_best_path=calloc(sizeof(int),size+1);

        MPI_Recv(&temp_best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // node è il rank del processo sorgente
        MPI_Recv(&temp_best_path[0], size+1, MPI_INT, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        if(temp_best_cost < best_cost) {    // Confronto tra il costo ricevuto e l'ottimo corrente
                winner=node;
                best_cost=temp_best_cost;
                for(j=0; j<size+1; j++)
                  best_path[j]=temp_best_path[j];
        }

            MPI_Send(&best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        printf("Best Path Found by node %i:\n", winner);
        printf("%i", best_path[0]);
        for(i=1; i<size+1; i++)
          printf(" –> %i",best_path[i]);
        printf("\nBest Cost Found: %i\n", best_cost);
      }
      else {
        MPI_Recv(&(matrix[0][0]), m_row*m_column, MPI_LONG, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        int i;
        for(i=rank; i<size; i+=(p-1)) {
            int *visited=calloc(sizeof(int), size+1);
            int *path=calloc(sizeof(int), size+1);
            int cost=matrix[0][i], path_i=1; // imposta cost al peso dell'arco tra 0 e il valore di rank
                                             // ad esempio (se rank = 1) cost = il peso dell'arco tra il nodo 0 e il nodo 1
            path[0]=0;
            visited[0]=1;
            dfs(i, visited, path, path_i, cost);

            MPI_Send(&best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&best_path[0], size+1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            MPI_Recv(&best_cost, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            free(visited);
            free(path);
        }
      }

      MPI_Finalize();
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If it's falling over with 20 nodes, it's probably a bad algorithm. OR-Tools implements a better one.

Comment: It sounds like every branch is fully explored. You could keep the minimum distance in a `MPI_Win` and use passive target synchronization to let a branch read it out and abort its search prematurely.

Comment: Do you Know where I can find a better code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp

Comment: Thank you so much. It would have been perfect with Branch & Bound (in C - MPI).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That's not really a code. That's the callbacks specification for some library. It's also not parallel. So it depends if the OP wants to learn something or just needs to have a problem solved.